# JavaFX: How to get more "dummy/empty Rows"

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a Javafx TableView where I can add new Rows by double Click on an empty Row at the End of my "filled" / Textfield filled Rows.
My Problem is,if i add some Rows ,Java don't give me more of the empty Rows I could double click to add some Rows.
Edit:removed some unnessary log

To see what i mean, here is the Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.util.Callback;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


interface inside_table
{
    public void Select_Row_by_Col(int index);
}

public class Supermain extends Application {
    ObservableList<myTextRow> data;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ArrayList myindizes=new ArrayList();



        final TableView<myTextRow> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.setStyle("-fx-text-wrap: true;");

        //Table columns
        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        clmID.setMinWidth(160);
        clmID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));

        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext = new TableColumn<>("Text");
        clmtext.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text"));
        clmtext.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory("text"));

        TableColumn<myTextRow, String> clmtext2 = new TableColumn<>("Text2");
        clmtext2.setMinWidth(160);
        clmtext2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("text2"));
        clmtext2.setCellFactory(new TextFieldCellFactory("text2"));

        //Add data
        data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new myTextRow(5, "Lorem","bla"),
                new myTextRow(2, "Ipsum","bla")
        );

        table.getColumns().addAll(clmID, clmtext,clmtext2);
        table.setItems(data);

        table.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                if (mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && mouseEvent.getY()>24) {
                        data.add(new myTextRow(td_get_biggest_ID() + 1,"",""));  
                        table.selectionModelProperty().get().select(data.size()-1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5.0);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Get Data");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (myTextRow data1 : data) {
                    System.out.println("data:" + data1.getText2());
                }
            }
        });

        hBox.getChildren().add(btn);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setCenter(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 640, 480));
        primaryStage.show();

        class I_table implements inside_table{

            @Override
            public void Select_Row_by_Col(int index) {
                table.getSelectionModel().select(index);
            }

        }


    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public static class TextFieldCellFactory
            implements Callback<TableColumn<myTextRow, String>, TableCell<myTextRow, String>> {

        private String ColumnName;

        public TextFieldCellFactory(String ColumnName){
        this.ColumnName=ColumnName;
        }

        @Override
        public TableCell<myTextRow, String> call(TableColumn<myTextRow, String> param) {
            TextFieldCell textFieldCell = new TextFieldCell(this.ColumnName);
            return textFieldCell;

        }

        public static class TextFieldCell extends TableCell<myTextRow, String> {

            private TextArea textField;
            private StringProperty boundToCurrently = null;
            private String last_text;
            private String ColumnName;


            public TextFieldCell(String cname) {

                textField = new TextArea();
                textField.setWrapText(true);
                textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
                last_text="";
                this.ColumnName=cname;



                this.setGraphic(textField);

                textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> { 
                    if(this.ColumnName=="text2"){
                        if(isNowFocused){last_text=textField.getText();System.out.println("NOW focus "+last_text);}
                        if (! isNowFocused && ! isValid(textField.getText())) { 
                            textField.setText(last_text);
                            //textField.setText("00:00:00:00");
                            textField.selectAll();
                            System.out.println("blur");

                        }
                    }

                });

            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    // Show the Text Field
                    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);


                   // myindizes.add(getIndex());

                    // Retrieve the actual String Property that should be bound to the TextField
                    // If the TextField is currently bound to a different StringProperty
                    // Unbind the old property and rebind to the new one
                    ObservableValue<String> ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());
                    SimpleStringProperty sp = (SimpleStringProperty) ov;

                    if (this.boundToCurrently == null) {
                        this.boundToCurrently = sp;
                        this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(sp);
                    } else if (this.boundToCurrently != sp) {
                        this.textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
                        this.boundToCurrently = sp;
                        this.textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(this.boundToCurrently);
                    }

                    double height = real_lines_height(textField.getText(), this.getWidth(), 30, 22);
                    textField.setPrefHeight(height);
                    textField.setMaxHeight(height);

                    textField.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                    // if height bigger than the biggest height in the row
                    //-> change all heights of the row(textfields ()typeof textarea) to this height
                    // else leave the height as it is


                    //System.out.println("item=" + item + " ObservableValue<String>=" + ov.getValue());
                    //this.textField.setText(item);  // No longer need this!!!
                } else {
                    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            }//update

            private boolean isValid(String s){

                String splitArray[] = s.split(":");
                if (splitArray.length != 4) {
                    System.out.println("false");
                    return false;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {

                    if (splitArray[i].length() != 2) {
                        System.out.println("false");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!splitArray[i].substring(0, 1).matches("[0-9]")) {
                        System.out.println("no number1");
                        return false;
                    }
                    if (!splitArray[i].substring(1, 2).matches("[0-9]")) {
                        System.out.println("no number2");
                        return false;
                    }

                    if (i < 3) {
                        int itest = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[i]);
                        if (itest > 59) {
                            System.out.println(itest + " ist zu groß!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        int itest2 = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[i]);
                        if (itest2 > Math.floor(25)) {
                            System.out.println(itest2 + " ist zu groß!");
                            return false;
                        }
                        //framerate!!!!!
                    }

                    System.out.println("splits: " + splitArray[i]);
                    //if( el.charAt(0).)
                }

                return true;

            }

        }

    }

    public class myTextRow {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty ID;

        private final SimpleStringProperty text;
        private final SimpleStringProperty text2;

        public myTextRow(int ID, String text,String text2) {

            this.ID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(ID);
            this.text = new SimpleStringProperty(text);
            this.text2 = new SimpleStringProperty(text2);


        }


        //setter
        public void setID(int id) {
            this.ID.set(id);
        }

        public void setText(String text) {
            this.text.set(text);
        }

        public void setText2(String text) {         
            this.text2.set(text);         
        }

       //getter
        public int getID() {
            return ID.get();
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text.get();
        }

        public String getText2() {
            return text2.get();
        }

        //properties
        public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text;

        }

        public StringProperty text2Property() {
        return text2;

        }

    public IntegerProperty IDProperty() {
        return ID;
    }

    }

    private static double real_lines_height(String s, double width, double heightCorrector, double widthCorrector) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label("Text");
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(h);
        l.applyCss();
        double line_height = l.prefHeight(-1);

        int new_lines = s.replaceAll("[^\r\n|\r|\n]", "").length();
        //  System.out.println("new lines= "+new_lines);
        String[] lines = s.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
        //  System.out.println("line count func= "+ lines.length);
        int count = 0;
        //double rest=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            double text_width = get_text_width(lines[i]);
            double plus_lines = Math.ceil(text_width / (width - widthCorrector));
            if (plus_lines > 1) {
                count += plus_lines;
                //rest+= (text_width / (width-widthCorrector)) - plus_lines;
            } else {
                count += 1;
            }

        }
        //count+=(int) Math.ceil(rest);
        count += new_lines - lines.length;

        return count * line_height + heightCorrector;
    }

    private static double get_text_width(String s) {
        HBox h = new HBox();
        Label l = new Label(s);
        l.setWrapText(false);
        h.getChildren().add(l);
        Scene sc = new Scene(h);
        l.applyCss();
        // System.out.println("FXMLDocumentController.get_text_width(): "+l.prefWidth(-1));
        return l.prefWidth(-1);

    }
    public int td_get_biggest_ID() {
        int biggest = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (((myTextRow) data.get(i)).getID() > biggest) {
                biggest = ((myTextRow) data.get(i)).getID();
            }
        }
        return biggest;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you add that local class that ins't used anywhere? Just to make us read through more code??? That interfact it implements isn't used anywhere else either. Please make sure [your code is minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you post a question.

Comment: I'm sorry.I didn't intend to add any unused code.which class do you actually mean, i get through the code,but I didn't found the class you've mentioned.

Comment: `I_table` / `inside_table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just click anywhere else on the `TableView` but make sure it's at least 24 pixels from the top; This will work since you've added the event handler is added to the `TableView`...

If you only want to use the last row, then use a custom `rowFactory` and handle the events there.

Add a placeholder item to the `TableView` items that marks the row that is used for adding new elements (for some reason the selection model doesn't like `null`):

```
final myTextRow addPlaceHolder = new myTextRow(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);

...

//Add data
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new myTextRow(5, "Lorem", "bla"),
        new myTextRow(2, "Ipsum", "bla"),
        addPlaceHolder
);
```

make sure your `TextFieldCell`s treat `null` values as empty rows:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (!empty && item != null) {
        // Show the Text Field
        this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
...
```

make sure the first column does not display anything for the placeholder

```
//Table columns
TableColumn<myTextRow, Number> clmID = new TableColumn<>("ID");
clmID.setMinWidth(160);
clmID.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> {
    myTextRow item = cdf.getValue();
    return item == addPlaceHolder ? Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> null) : item.IDProperty();
});
```

and use the following `rowFactory` to handle adding the items (you don't need the `updateItem` part unless you need to add a style class to the `TableRow`; you need not extend `TableRow` in this case)

```
table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<myTextRow>() {
    {
        setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
            if (mouseEvent.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY
                    && mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2
                    && !isEmpty()
                    && getItem() == addPlaceHolder) {
                data.add(data.size() - 1, new myTextRow(td_get_biggest_ID() + 1, "", ""));
                table.selectionModelProperty().get().select(data.size() - 1);
                mouseEvent.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(myTextRow item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        // add style class for row containing addPlaceHolder
        List<String> classes = getStyleClass();
        final String clazz = "add-row";

        if (item == addPlaceHolder) {
            if (!classes.contains(clazz)) {
                classes.add(clazz);
            }
        } else {
            classes.remove(clazz);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is almost a solution for me,but it is not really good,because the space is too small.I want to have a few of this empty rows,that my rows are not on the edge of the table.If I add some more of your placeholders to have more space, it happens that the new "real" rows are in between the empty and the new row. Increase the PrefHeight fails,too, because I lost the control of the heights of the other cells.Isn't there another way to force java to add some of its natural default empty rows,which are generated automatically to fill the table at the start?